# Electronic specific heat capacity using free electron theory

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, fermi-energy

While considering the contribution of the electronic specific heat capacity, it is stated that, when the temperature increases from 0 K , only the electrons with energy range of the order of $k_bT$ from the Fermi energy are excited. How was this range determined? (Ref: [Introduction to Solid State Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Solid_State_Physics), 8th Edition by Charles Kittel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an approximate statement, which follows from understanding the shape of the Fermi distribution:
$$
n_F(E) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{E - E_F}{k_B T}} + 1}
$$
This distribution has a step-like form: it is approximately 1 for $E < E_F$ and approximately zero for $E > E_F$, except for the region around $E_F$ where $|E-E_F|\sim k_B T$. In the limit of very low temperatures this region is nearly non-existent and the distribution becomes a step-function
$$
n_F(E) = \theta (E_F - E).
$$
Broadening of this region when the temperature increases is what one refers to as the electrons excited above the Fermi surface (i.e. some states below $E_F$ are not fully filled, and some states above $E_F$ now contain electrons. But the states away from this region are still either filled (occupancy $1$) or empty (occupancy $0$).